# How to make URL for visiting post author's profile page from the post page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have a model called `Product` that has a `user` field, and a `Profile` model that also has a `user` field. What i want is: When `user` `A` post something from a `Product` model, and `user` `B` also post something from the `Product` model, I want to redirect visitors or others user to the `public_profile` page of the user who created that `Product` model object.

For Example:
In Stack Overflow, when the user ask a question, you can see their username on that question and anyone in the world can go to that profile page of that user that created that question.

urls:

```
    path('/<slug:slug>/', views.public_profile, name='Public-Profile'),
```

views:

```
def public_profile(request, slug):

    return render(request, 'public_profile.html')
```

my template:

```
{% for product in products %}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card my-2 shadow-sm bg-body">
                    <div class="card-head">
                         
                        I want add the url to this `a` tag
                        <a href="{% url 'Public-Profile' %}">

                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                                account_circle
                                </span>
                            {{ user.username }}
                        </a>
                    </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

my models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product-image')
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=11)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile-image', default='static/dafault.jpg')
    twitter = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    linkedln = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True,)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=700, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.user)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a method `get_user_public_profile_url` in your Product model, which returns the profile URL of the product.user

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

    def get_user_public_profile_url(self):
        return reverse('Public-Profile', kwargs={'slug': self.user.profile.slug})
```

and in your template, change this line

```
<a href="{% url 'Public-Profile' %}">
```

to

```
<a href="{{ product.get_user_public_profile_url }}">
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I access the user profile object in the `public_profile` view?

Comment: You can do the same, where ever you can put the ```{{ product }}``` instance, there you can call ```{{ product.get_user_public_profile_url }}```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `slug` parameter to your url, that leads to the product  related user profile slug `product.user.profile.slug`

```
{% for product in products %}
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card my-2 shadow-sm bg-body">
            <div class="card-head">
                <a href="{% url 'Public-Profile' slug=product.user.profile.slug %}">
                    <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                        account_circle
                    </span>
                    {{ product.user.username }}
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```